# Spring 3 validation throws java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: spring

**My Validator Class**

```
 public class ProductValidator implements Validator {
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) throws ValidatorException {
        Product product =(Product)obj;
        if("NONE".equals(product.getCategory())){
            errors.rejectValue("category","Category Required");
        }
    }
```

**My jsp**

```
 <form:select path="category" cssClass="add">
        <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select Category ---"/>
    <form:options items="${categoryList}" itemValue="categoryId" itemLabel="categoryName"/>             
</form:select>       
<form:errors path="category" cssClass="error"> </form:errors>
```

When I submit the form without selecting any option it gives error as,

Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.main.java.Category for property category; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.main.java.Category] for property category: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Any thing wrong here?

Please help.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing selected you are submitting "NONE" String to your controller.

```
    <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select Category ---"/>
```

This is why you are getting this exception